# in IBM BPM/BAW spark toolkit Table control How to loop the table control object in to the table control load

Tags: javascript, ibm-bpm, spark-ui

I am trying to loop the table and get the one column value and do the check with other value. Following code i am using to do that. but i couldnt able to get the data and loop.

```js
var tableControlData=${tableControlCID}.getData();
var matchingValue=${matchedControlCID}.getData();
var conditionPassed=false;
if(matchingValue){
  for(var i=0; i<tableControlData.length; i++){
   var columnValue=tableControlData.get(i).get("column2");
   if(columnValue){
      if(columnValue == matchingValue){
          conditionPassed = true;
      }
      break;
   }
  }
}
```